# Some Netflix videos are showing horizontal tearing (flickering lines)

Tags: linux, xorg, video

Some videos I watch on Netflix under Linux are show horizontal flicker.  How do I fix it?

I have a on-board ATI Radeon graphics chip (specifically a AMD A8-7600 Radeon R7) using the open source Radeon driver.  I'm viewing Netflix in Chrome (stable, ver 52.0.2743.116) and am using Widevine Content Decryption Module (version 1.4.8.893) to view Netflix.  My OS is Fedora 24 (kernel 4.6.5) and my desktop is KDE.

Comment: Do the same videos appear OK on a different computer?  What is your graphics adapter?  What is your operating system and which video driver are you using?  Is the issue related to the resolution of the video or anything that could be constant?  This is a quick overview of what should be included in your question.

Comment: Since I was doing this Q&A style, answering my own question, I thought it would be okay to put that sort of info into the answer.

Comment: I tend to agree with Julie, maybe because there was another instance of this earlier today, but -- Questions should stand on their own, with enough detail in them that future problem-havers or problem-solvers can find the question and solve The Problem.

Comment: Think of a question that went "I have a movie file with funny characters in it that I can't remove; how do I fix it?" The actual problem could be any number of things, so narrowing down the actual problem helps everyone.

Comment: All that being said, thank you for sharing what you've learned to fix your own problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a [Radeon video card](https://www.x.org/wiki/RadeonFeature/), you can turn on the "[TearFree](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ATI#Driver_options)" Xorg option.  To determine if you have a Radeon video card, trying `lsmod | grep radeon`  should get you something like:

```
radeon               1507328  13
```

Or do `grep -i radeon /var/log/Xorg.0.log | more` and the first few lines should be something like:

```
[478553.078] (**) |   |-->Device "Radeon"
[478553.091] (II) LoadModule: "radeon"
[478553.091] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/radeon_drv.so
[478553.091] (II) Module radeon: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
```

Having determined that you're using a Radeon card, go to directory `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` and, as root, create a file named `20-radeon.conf` containing the following lines.

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Radeon"
    Driver "radeon"

    Option "TearFree" "on"
EndSection
```

Finally restart the Xorg server by logging out of your desktop session and logging back in.

(***NOTE***: A similar solution might work for those with an [Intel graphics card](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/intel_graphics#Tear-free_video), though keep in mind that the `Driver` argument will have to be different and the `Option` value will have to be `true` rather than `on`).